# Mifare Plus X authentication response 0x06

Tags: apdu, mifare

I'm trying to authenticate in Mifare Plus X card via AES key. Let me show all steps:

1. Authenticate with key A in sector 1.
   Send first authentication command to MP: 70 02 40 00.
   Response: 907EAF3F73ADD8B212E63201727CE016BF, where 90 status code and the rest bytes are encrypted RndB
2. Decrypting response and get RndB, rotate it to the left and get RndB'.
3. Generate RndA, 16-byte length
4. Encrypt RndA+RndB'
5. Send second authentication command to MP: 72 + En(RndA+RndB').
   Response: 06

Now I don't know what byte 0x06 means. Please, can somebody help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It means to fail authentication. It fails due to wrong card type or sam.